# C# WPF обработать событие TextBox, который внутри ListBoxItem Control Template

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListBoxItem у которого есть Control Template внутри которого есть TextBox (IsEnabled = false), которому нужно сказать ставать IsEnabled = true когда MouseDoubleClick. Как работать с событиями контролов которые внутри Control Template другого контрола? (Control Template внутри Resource Dictionary)

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="CustomControlTemplate">
   <TextBox IsEnabled="false" MouseDoubleClick="TextBoxMouseDoublieClick"/>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Создайте метод для обработки события **TextBoxMouseDoublieClick** и обрабатывайте клики по вашему элементу. В метод будет передаваться объект который вызвал это событие. Вот его и используйте, только приведите его к **TextBox**  экземпляру.

Comment: @Rootware где создать? как присоеденить к MouseDoubleClick в Control Template?

Comment: В XAML редакторе щёлкните двойным кликом мыши по названию события **TextBoxMouseDoublieClick** и метод-обработчик автоматически создастся в коде обработчика окна.

Comment: нету окна) решил проблему с помощю user control и dependency property

Comment: Ну раз окна у вас нет, то все контролы в воздухе висят. А xaml код вы пишите вилами на воде.

Comment: *Как работать с событиями контролов которые внутри Control Template другого контрола?* — а зачем? Мне кажется здесь уже пора переходить к полноценному UserControl